# Failed HttpWebRequest is automatically resend

Tags: c#, compact-framework, httplistener

When I send a HttpWebRequest to an unreachable web server it times out as expected but it gets resend as soon as the web server is online. The web server tries to read the request body which causes an HttpListnerException with error code 995.

```
System.Net.HttpListenerException (0x80004005): The I/O operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or an application request.
   at System.Net.HttpRequestStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   at System.IO.StreamReader.ReadBuffer()
   at System.IO.StreamReader.ReadToEnd()
```

Here is the code:

**Client .NET CF 3.5 running on a Windows Mobile 6.5 emulator:**

```
var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://servername:9999/");
request.Method = "POST";
request.Timeout = 1000;
var requestBodyBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("foobar");
request.ContentType = "text/plain";
request.ContentLength = requestBodyBytes.Length;
using (var requestStream = request.GetRequestStream())
{
    requestStream.Write(requestBodyBytes, 0, requestBodyBytes.Length);
}
using (var response = request.GetResponse())
using (var responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
using (var responseStreamReader = new StreamReader(responseStream))
{
    return responseStreamReader.ReadToEnd();
}
```

**Server .NET Framework 4.5:**

```
using (var listener = new HttpListener())
{
    var shutdown = new ManualResetEvent(false); 
    var worker = new Thread(() =>   
    {
        var signals = new WaitHandle[] { shutdown, null };
        listener.Prefixes.Add("http://servername:9999/");       
        listener.Start();
        for (;;)
        {
            try     
            {
                var contextResult = listener.BeginGetContext(null, null);
                signals[1] = contextResult.AsyncWaitHandle;
                if (WaitHandle.WaitAny(signals) == 0)
                    return;     
                var context = listener.EndGetContext(contextResult);
                var request = context.Request;
                using (var requestStream = request.InputStream)
                using (var requestStreamReader = new StreamReader(requestStream))
                {
                    requestStreamReader.ReadToEnd();
                }
                var responseBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(String.Format("Hello {0}", DateTime.Now));
                using (var response = context.Response)
                using (var responseStream = response.OutputStream)
                {
                    response.ContentType = "text/plain";
                    response.ContentLength64 = responseBytes.Length;
                    responseStream.Write(responseBytes, 0, responseBytes.Length);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                // The HttpListenerException mentioned above gets thrown here.
                MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());
            }
        }
    });
    worker.Start();
    MessageBox.Show("Click OK to exit.");
    shutdown.Set();
    worker.Join();
}
```

To reproduce the error I must do the following:

1. Send one or more web requests before the web server is started which results in a WebException on the client because the requests time out
2. Don't close the client application
3. Start the web server
4. Watch as the WebServer receives the web requests that the client previously sent and tries to read the request body which results in the above mentioned HttpListenerException

The error only occurs only if I run the client code on a Windows Mobile device using the Compact Framework in constrast to running it on a desktop.

How can I prevent the Windows Mobile client from resending timed out requests?